# thrust copy_if with const source

Tags: cuda, constants, gpu, thrust, const-iterator

My problem is in the following code:

The filter function compiles, and runs as it should when the source is not constant (the iterators are adjusted accordingly). However when I change the source to const, the compiler gives me the following error for the first two variables of the copy_if statement:
"the object has type qualifiers that are not compatible with the member function".

I believe there is a const to not const conversion error somewhere but frankly I have no idea where. Any help would be appreciated.

```
#include "thrust\device_vector.h"
#include "thrust\copy.h"

typedef thrust::device_vector<float>::const_iterator    Dc_FloatIterator;
typedef thrust::device_vector<float>::iterator          D_FloatIterator;

typedef thrust::device_vector<int>::const_iterator  Dc_IntIterator;
typedef thrust::device_vector<int>::iterator        D_IntIterator;

typedef thrust::tuple< Dc_IntIterator, Dc_IntIterator, Dc_FloatIterator> Dc_ListIteratorTuple;
typedef thrust::zip_iterator<Dc_ListIteratorTuple>   Dc_ListIterator;//type of the class const iterator

typedef thrust::tuple< D_IntIterator, D_IntIterator, D_FloatIterator > D_ListIteratorTuple;
typedef thrust::zip_iterator<D_ListIteratorTuple>    D_ListIterator;//type of the class iterator

struct selector{//selector functor for the copy if call
const int val;

selector(int _val) : val(_val) {}

__host__ __device__
bool operator()(const int& x ) {
return ( x == val );
   }
};

class Foo{    
public:
    thrust::device_vector<int>      ivec1;
    thrust::device_vector<int>      ivec2;
    thrust::device_vector<float>    fvec1;

    Foo(){;}
    ~Foo(){;}

    D_ListIterator begin(){//cast of begin iterator
        return D_ListIterator(D_ListIteratorTuple( ivec1.begin(), ivec2.begin(), fvec1.begin() ));
    }
    D_ListIterator end(){//cast of end iterator
        return D_ListIterator(D_ListIteratorTuple( ivec1.end(), ivec2.end(), fvec1.end() ));
    }

    Dc_ListIterator cbegin(){//cast of const begin iterator
        return Dc_ListIterator(Dc_ListIteratorTuple( ivec1.cbegin(), ivec2.cbegin(), fvec1.cbegin() ));
    }
    Dc_ListIterator cend(){//cast of const end iterator
        return Dc_ListIterator(Dc_ListIteratorTuple( ivec1.cend(), ivec2.cend(), fvec1.cend() ));
    }

    void const_filter( const Foo& TheOther, const int& target ){//doesnt work
        //This function should copy those member of the vectors where
        //the ivec2[i] == target is true
        thrust::copy_if(
            TheOther.cbegin(),
            TheOther.cend(),
            TheOther.ivec2.cbegin(),
            this->begin(),
            selector(target) );
    }
    void filter( Foo& TheOther, const int& target ){//works
        //This function should copy those member of the vectors where
        //the ivec2[i] == target is true
        thrust::copy_if(
            TheOther.begin(),
            TheOther.end(),
            TheOther.ivec2.cbegin(),
            this->begin(),
            selector(target) );
    }
    void insert(const int& one, const int& two,const float& three ){
        ivec1.push_back(one);
        ivec2.push_back(two);
        fvec1.push_back(three);
    }

    int size(){
        return ivec1.size();
    }
};

bool CheckIfSublistIsConnected(const Foo& list,const int& sublist_num){
Foo tmp;

tmp.const_filter( list, sublist_num );

return (bool)tmp.size();//for symplicity, othervise here is a function that check if
                        //the edge list represents a connected graph
}
int main(void){
Foo list;
bool connected;
list.insert(10,2,1.0);
list.insert(11,2,1.0);
list.insert(12,2,1.0);
list.insert(10,3,1.0);
list.insert(10,3,1.0);

connected=CheckIfSublistIsConnected(list,2); 

if( connected ) return 0;
else return -1;
}
```

I've found that replacing `TheOther.cbegin() / .cend()` with the folowing the compiler accepts it. This means I messed up somewhere in the typedef section, but where?

```
    thrust::make_zip_iterator(
        thrust::make_tuple(
            TheOther.ivec1.cbegin(),
            TheOther.ivec2.cbegin(),
            TheOther.fvec1.cbegin() ))
```

Comment: can you provide a complete example showing the call to `Foo::filter` in the passing/compiling case, and the call to `Foo::filter` with parameters that cause the compile to fail?

Comment: It's not really complete.  I don't know what `cbegin()` and `cend()` look like.  Can you create a simple, compilable example that demonstrates the problem, but doesn't have any unnecessary code in it to demonstrate the problem?  I'd like something I can copy, paste, and compile without having to edit anything or add anything.

Comment: I edited a code that shows the problem, you can try and compile it. While constructing this sample I noticed that if the filter(...) call takes only a Foo& (not const) and I call cend and cbegin it works. However in my real program this call is made ~5 calls deep, and the first function takes Foo as const reference as well, so I have to pass it as const reference.

Comment: I also added the `const` to the `cend` and `cbegin` definitions, and the (compile) problem went away.  Does this mean you've solved your problem?  If so, could you please post it as an answer and I will upvote it. (It seems this is not a thrust issue?)  Thanks.

Comment: Done, and thanks for trying to help. In this project 90% of my bugs are thrust related so I assumed this one too to be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it comes out I've frogotten to add the const magic word at the definition of cend/cbegin.

```
Dc_ListIterator cbegin() const {
        return Dc_ListIterator(Dc_ListIteratorTuple( ivec1.cbegin(), ivec2.cbegin(), fvec1.cbegin() ));
    }
Dc_ListIterator cend() const {
        return Dc_ListIterator(Dc_ListIteratorTuple( ivec1.cend(), ivec2.cend(), fvec1.cend() ));
    }
```